# saving time as per the user selected time_zone specified in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a scenario where I have events, and events has_many sessions. The events table has time_zone field and the session start_time and end_time is related to this time zone. I want to store the start_time and end_time in UTC format in the db and display the time as per the events time_zone. Also what would be the unit test scenarios for the above case.

Answer (score 1):

In ROR database always stores time in UTC format, to display time according to zone you can use

```
start_time.in_time_zone(time_zone).strftime("%b %e, %a %l:%M %p %Z")
```

eg.

```
start_time.in_time_zone('Mumbai').strftime("%b %e, %a %l:%M %p %Z")
```